# C# XML REST API response => Object

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I'm querying an API which returns a response in XML, so I've been looking into [Controlling XML Serialization Using Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28VS.80%29.aspx) .

The API response looks like this:
[image]
What I want to do is takes all the CampaignDTO elements (0..*) and put them in a list. How could this be done? I keep running into errors because of the Totalcount element at the end.

```
public class Campaign
    {
        #region CTor
        public Campaign()
        {
        }
        #endregion

        #region Properties

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id_campaign")]
        public string ID_Campaign { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Campaignname")]
        public string ElementName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Websiteurl")]
        public string WebsiteUrl { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Privacypolicyurl")]
        public string PrivacyPolicyUrl { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Termsurl")]
        public string TermsUrl { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Pricepageurl")]
        public string PricepageUrl { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Maxcredit")]
        public Int32 MaxCredit { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fk_id_currency")]
        public string FK_ID_Currency { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Maxscans")]
        public short MaxScans { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Startdate")]
        public DateTime Startdate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Enddate")]
        public DateTime Enddate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Starthour")]
        public short Starthour { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Endhour")]
        public short Endhour { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Pmam")]
        public string PMAM { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Language")]
        public string Language { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fk_id_merchantapp")]
        public string FK_ID_MerchantApp { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Campaigntype")]
        public string CampaignType { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Createtimestamp")]
        public DateTime CreateTimestamp { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Lastupdate")]
        public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Lastupdateby")]
        public string LastUpdateBy { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Status")]
        public short Status { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: You would do better to post the actual XML, as XML, instead of posting a picture of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define the object model corresponding to the xml correctly. Based on the sample xml above, I've come up with the below model

```
[XmlRoot("CampaignListXml")]
public class CampaignList
{
    [XmlElement]
    public Allcampaign Allcampaign;

    [XmlElement]
    public int TotalCount;
}

public class Allcampaign
{
    [XmlElement("CompaignDTO", typeof(Campaign))]
    public Campaign[] CampaignArray;
}

public class Campaign
{
    #region CTor
    public Campaign()
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id_campaign")]
    public string ID_Campaign { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Campaignname")]
    public string ElementName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Websiteurl")]
    public string WebsiteUrl { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Privacypolicyurl")]
    public string PrivacyPolicyUrl { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Termsurl")]
    public string TermsUrl { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Pricepageurl")]
    public string PricepageUrl { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Maxcredit")]
    public Int32 MaxCredit { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fk_id_currency")]
    public string FK_ID_Currency { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Maxscans")]
    public short MaxScans { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Startdate")]
    public DateTime Startdate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Enddate")]
    public DateTime Enddate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Starthour")]
    public short Starthour { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Endhour")]
    public short Endhour { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Pmam")]
    public string PMAM { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fk_id_merchantapp")]
    public string FK_ID_MerchantApp { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Campaigntype")]
    public string CampaignType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Createtimestamp")]
    public DateTime CreateTimestamp { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Lastupdate")]
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Lastupdateby")]
    public string LastUpdateBy { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Status")]
    public short Status { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Now you can construct the object from xml as below

```
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CampaignList));
    CampaignList x1 = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as CampaignList;
    Compaign[] compaignArray = x1.Allcompaign.CompaignArray; //This will have all the compaign list
}
```

Hope this helps.